# Ionic App - Monospaced Angular QR Code download function is not working on android

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using this plugin provided by monospaced [Angular QR Code](https://github.com/monospaced/angular-qrcode) on github, everything goes well but the download function is not working when the app is installed in android.

It says

> as downloadable image

```
<qrcode data="string" download></qrcode>
```

The above code will produce a QR Code image that is clickable to download, it is working well in browsers, but nothing happens on the device when I clicked it.

Here is the demo of the plugin which is working really well in browsers

http://monospaced.github.io/angular-qrcode